# Validity of: ◻◇◻p → ◇p in transitive frames

Tags: logic, modal-logic

How can I show the (in)validity of:  ◻◇◻p → ◇p in a transitive frame?

Proof method:
I want to do this by showing in a transitive frame that ◻◇◻p holds and that ◇p doesn't hold.

(I think that ◻◇◻p would never hold in an transitive frame and that the implication is then automatically right, is this correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:

```
(1) ~(◻◇◻p → ◇p)  (ass., for RAA)      
(2) ◻◇◻p (from 1)
(3) ~◇p  (from 1)
```

You should be able to derive `~◇◻p` from (3) in a few steps, and get a contradiction by deriving `◇◻p` from (2).

Regarding your second question, doesn't `◻◇◻p` "hold" in the single-world model w1: {p = True}?